# Automated way to port Javascript to c++

Tags: javascript, c++

Is there any program which does this?

I mean, V8 does this at runtime under the hood, but is there any way to output the c++ code?

We need a javascript to c++ converter or translator.

Comment: When it comes down to it, any code is just data.  It's parsed by the interpreter.  It wouldn't be such a longshot that you could take the parsed data, and compile into code that would be readable by C++.  V8 does something like this when it interprets at runtime, creating some C-type low level abstraction of the JS code.  Watch some V8 stuff and you'll understand what I'm talking about.  As for your suggestion to read programming books, I find it to be coming from an unstable and overly emotional place.  Perhaps you should meditate.  This is a place to be constructive, not to quickdraw.

Comment: For the other way, there is emscripten https://github.com/kripken/emscripten
I don't know of a JS->C++ compiler. In the earlier days of compilers, it was quite common to create a compiler that creates C-code and then let a C compiler create the machine-code to support different platforms. Today, there are indermediate "languages" like LLVM or gcc intermediate code from which the compiler creates machine code.

Comment: @josef Ah yes, I remember looking at that when I was considering faster 3d / physics implementations in js.

Comment: Do you want to *port* JS code to C++, as in translate the code into something that can be maintained, or do you want to *compile* JS code to C++, as in produce C++ code just to then compile it to native code with a C++ compiler? Or is the purpose to call code written in JS from a C++ program?

Comment: Ideally it'd be human readable C++ code, but I've considered if it weren't.  Basically I've got some JS code and it needs to go on a microcontroller, so I'll probably have to write some C++ code to do the same thing.

Comment: The v8 engine does not transpile javascript to c++. It compiles javascript code to machine code at runtime which the computer then runs. Of course it would be possible for v8 and other js engines to transpile js to c++ and then compile the c++ but that's just an extra step and would not be performant. They could just as well transpile it to php or ruby. I don't know of a js to c++ transpiler but you could create one. If you say that v8 does it you could grab the code out of the chromium project, good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only project I found still working in that direction is JXcore.
[Initially](http://jxcore.com/jxcore-llvm-javascript-frontend-b/)(not valid link), they planned to switch from V8 to a LLVM based JS engine in version 2.
That goal seems to have moved to "Down the Road" [currently](http://jxcore.com/downloads/)(web down) and isn't even in the [roadmap](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/ROADMAP.md) anymore.

Mozilla was looking into using LLVM in 2009 and [stopped that efforts](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/tracemonkey-overview/comment-page-2/#comment-67629) too.

It seems there is no speed gain in compiling JavaScript to machine code (modern engines do that with their jit compilers for the parts of the code where it makes a difference) and the work just isn't worth it.

Comment: As of 2015/09/01, this is on the roadmap of JXCore. "Compiled JavaScript for Mobile Applications". It is marked as 'almost ready'.

Comment: The [NectarJS](https://github.com/NectarJS/nectarjs) compiler is also able to translate JavaScript programs into C++.